# Prove that $a_n$ $\rightarrow$ L $\implies$ |$a_n$| $\rightarrow$ |L|

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The book I am using for my Advance Calculus course is Introduction to Analysis by Arthur Mattuck.

Prove that $a_n$ $\rightarrow$ L $\implies$ |$a_n$| $\rightarrow$ |L|.
We are needed to make a cases to use theorem 5.3B

[image]

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time it is greatly appreciated.So lets begin:

Proof:

[image]

Comment: Don't worry, it is perfect.

Comment: Looks good. The lines 6 and 7 [could be reduced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality). *No need* for Theorem 5.3B.